# Need job generator to output two items from lists

Tags: python, list, class, methods

first time posting and very new to python (3 weeks in). As I'm trying to get a better understanding of classes, this is a job generator that outputs teams (lists) of two or more different names: one with value over 3 (or “M”) and one lower. Need help with the part beginning with the 2 asteriks. Keeps giving me error that str object has no attribute “name.

```
import random
class Rankings:
    ranks = ["","T","B","M","P","C"] #rankings going in order #from least to greatest with index being a respective value of #the ranking. Ex. C = 5, P = 4....
    listofranks = []
    num_of_emps =[]
    def __init__(self,name,ranking):
        self.name = name #mover’s name 
        Rankings.num_of_emps.append(self.name)#adds #mover to list once created 
        self.ranking = ranking #mover’s ranking 
        Rankings.listofranks.append(self.ranking) #adds ranking #to list once created 
    def rank(self):
        self.ranking = Rankings.ranks[self.ranking] 
        return self.ranking #returns the mover’s respective rank #letter 
    def find_hi_rank(self):
        **hirank = [self.name in Rankings.num_of_emps for i in Rankings.listofranks if i > 3 ]** #Obviously this part is #confusing as I don’t know what to do to get what I want. I #want it to print name for each item w value greater than 3
        return hirank
    @classmethod
    def fromstring(cls,rank_str):
        name,ranking = rank_str.split("-")
        return cls(name,ranking)

    Tim = Rankings("Tim", 5)
    Luis = Rankings("Luis", 5)
    Chris = Rankings("Chris", 4)
    Fab = Rankings("Fab",3)
    G = Rankings("G", 3)
    Everett = Rankings("Everett", 3)
    print(Rankings.num_of_emps)      

    numofjobs = 3
    numofmovers = len(Rankings.num_of_emps)#how ever #many movers were added is the number of movers that can #be chosen from 
    movers = Rankings.num_of_emps
    job = 0
    while numofjobs >0:
        job +=1
        crew = int(input(f"How many movers are on job {job} ? "))
        #if crew < movers:
            #raiseError: Not enough movers
        groups = []
        numofmovers -= crew
        numofjobs -=1
        for i in range(crew):
            if i == 0:
                new = list(map(Rankings.find_hi_rank, movers))
                ",".split(new)# creates a list of movers that are #ranked higher than 3
                if len(new) == 0: 
                    break
                first = random.choice(new)
                groups.append(first)
            else: 
                second = random.choice(movers)
                groups.append(second)
                movers.remove(second)
        print("Movers:", groups)
```

Comment: @Nihal thank you for your indentation edit

Comment: `new = list(map(Rankings.find_hi_rank, movers))`  <-- you're calling a `find_hi_rank()` method as if it was a static/class method whereas you've intended it as an instance method. Its `self` attribute doesn't refer to any instance so whatever is in `movers` gets mapped to it (essentially names of your _rankings_) as the `self` attribute. Given that those are strings - you get the error when attempting to access `self.name`.